# Unity baking fails : OpenRL reported error code 501

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to bake a scene in Unity and get the following error :

```
OpenRL reported error code 501 : OpenRL error occured in function rlViewport: RL_INVALID_VALUE: Argument "width" or "height" is negative
```

Any leads about what could be causing this?

I am using the progressive lightmapper and tried clearing the Global GI cache and setting different objects as static / not static with no result.

Answer (score 0):

You may have inserted glowing objects into the scene and made them static. Hence, the light map is also static but unity does not bake such things well. Sorry for my English